# C#.NET Webservices using HTTPGET Returns System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've setup this example web service to investigate the source of my error:

```
    namespace userControlPanel.webservice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public OutputData1 AjaxGetMore(InputData1 input)
        {
            return new OutputData1()
            {
                id = input.id,
                message = "it's work!",
                myInt = input.myInt + 1
            };
        }

    }
    public class OutputData1
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public int myInt { get; set; }
    }
    public class InputData1
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int myInt { get; set; }
    }

}
```

It's based on an example here

So I've attempted to fetch a result here:

```
http://localhost:57109/webservice/WebService1.asmx/AjaxGet?id=li1234
```

And I get the result,

```
 System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

So, I assume it's web.config right? So I implement suggested setup (PS, I've also created a HTTP-POST web-service and it WORKS just great)

From web.config:

```
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this issue was the result of some poor code re-factoring and class/name-space issues on my part.

Also, would like to note that staying away form HTTPGET when using jQuery webservices is a good idea, re-information I've read [here](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)